# Bounds and constraints in Django ForeignKey field values -- and how they can effect queryset results

Tags: django, orm, django-models, one-to-many, django-database

For example if I have models.py like this:

```
Handler(models.Model):
    model1 = ForeignKey(Model1)
    model2 = ForeigKey(Model2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

For example there are 100 instances of Handler with Model1 id = 1, but Model 2 id for this 100 instances is in range 1 to 5. And when I do something like this:

```
Handles.objects.filter(model1=1).values_list('model2_id', flat=True)
```

It returns list of 5 id values or list of 100 id values, which are be repeated?
And if it return 100 values is there possibility to remain only one value for every repeated value?

Comment: You can fire up the Django shell, see and tweak your queries instantaneously.

Comment: No, I can't. I get error like django.settings is undefined and I can't.

Comment: Use `python manage.py shell` from your project directory.

Comment: raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return a list of 100 id values.
If you want to get the unique 5 ones, then you can do that in python.

```
model2_id_uniq_values = list(set(Handles.objects.filter(model1=1).values_list('model2_id', flat=True)))
```

It may not be the most finely tuned algorithm, and by using a set, you would lose the order. But for your purposes it appears to work.